# Change UINavigationbar background colour and title font/colour programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, ios11, appdelegate

I want to change the navigation bar background colour, title font and colour programmatically in iOS 11 and swift 4 from AppDelegate. I know how to do it using Xcode but didn't find up-to-date solution for doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code to change background colour and Title font.

```
func setupNavigationBarAppearance() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.imageFromColor(.black, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero, resizingMode: .tile)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

    let font:UIFont = UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Bold", size: 18.0)!
    let navbarTitleAtt = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font:font,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
    ]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = navbarTitleAtt
}
```

And call this func in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as setupNavigationBarAppearance(). I am using this same code, and it is working fine.

Comment: thx. and i used this line for nav bar tint :         UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.accent

Comment: This answer will set the appearance for all the navigation bars in your app. If you need to change for just one controller try the answer below by : **Kamal Kumar Lakshman**

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps for doing it for only specific ViewControllers.

I have created a BaseViewController file which is the parent for all of my ViewControllers. And the following code as been added to the viewDidLoad() of the BaseViewController.

1. For changing the Navigation bar's background color

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
   ```
2. For changing Navigation bar's title and Bar button colors

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
   ```
3. For changing font

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.red, NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.sourceSansPro(ofSize: 18.0), NSAttributedStringKey.kern:1.5]
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `UINavigationBar.appearance()`

For example:

`UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]`

or

`UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .blue`

Answer (score 2):

For **AppDelegate**:

Put following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 14.0/255.0, blue: 74.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: NSAttributedStringKey has been renamed, so now this line should be: `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]`

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 15 it is now

```
navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
```